# Bad Flag error in opencv 3.0

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++

I am relatively new to opencv and C++ and I would like some help on my code. For my project, I am currently working on a simple blob detector but when I run it, I get **"OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 2494
Press any key to continue . . ."**. I am pretty sure that the error is either from the Mat im_with_keypoints;, or a problem in linker. Below is my code. If you could help me that would be great.

- Update: I ran this program through the debugger and came out with this error

  - I am also using visual studio 2015

This is the image I am trying to detect for blobs:

[image: Picture is of 5 coins (eagle coins to be specific)]

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"  
#include "opencv2/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{


    Mat im = imread("Eagle_coins.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);


    SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;

    params.minThreshold = 10;
    params.maxThreshold = 200;

    params.filterByColor = true;

    params.filterByCircularity = true;
    params.minCircularity = 0.1;
    params.maxCircularity = 0.28;


    params.filterByConvexity = true;
    params.minConvexity = 0.87;
    params.maxConvexity = 2.8;


    params.filterByInertia = true;
    params.minInertiaRatio = 0.01;
    params.maxInertiaRatio = 2;

    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;

    Ptr<SimpleBlobDetector> detector = SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);

    detector->detect(im, keypoints);

    Mat im_with_keypoints;
    drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, im_with_keypoints, Scalar(0, 0, 255),                       DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);

    imshow("white", im_with_keypoints);
    waitKey(0);

}
```

Comment: Did you try running it in the debugger? What did that tell you? There's no need to guess.

Comment: @Dan Mašek I ran the program through the debugger and came out with the runtime error

Comment: You should be able to break to the debugger when the error occurs, and inspect the stack trace to see where exactly in your code this happens. Then you can use the debugger to further inspect the arguments to whatever it is you're calling that fails, in order to get more insight into the problem. | It would be useful if you attached a copy of your input image, in order to allow others to reproduce it. | Another thing you can mention is which mode you compiled your program in (Debug or Release?) and which libraries (the names) you linked it with.

Comment: @Dan Mašek Sorry for the late response, I did what you proposed as put in break points throughout the code, however, the program would not run regardless where I put the break point (I started from the end and worked to the begging). I have the code in debug mode. And the libraries I have linked were vc12, as well as the opencv_world300d.lib for the additional dependencies.

Comment: No problem. Do I assume correctly that you're using Visual Studio 2013? Please, edit your question and add the image you're using to test this, so we can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Dan Mašek I have updated the question. However, I cannot display the image due to my newness to the website. And I am using visual studio 2015. Could the issue be related to my Mat image? I am looking online and this seems like a common occurrence, . Thank you for your help.

Comment: OK, now it's obvious. You're using Visual Studio 2015, which comes with Visual C++ compiler version 14.0. However, you are linking with libraries labeled as `vc12` -- that means they're for compiler (and runtime) version  12.0, which is part of Visual Studio 2013. You need to use the correct set of libraries, those tagged as `vc14`. Also, the latest version of OpenCV is 3.1 so you may as well grab that.

Comment: @Dan Mašek I just linked the libraries for OpenCV 3.1 with the vc14 library, however, I am still getting the same error

Comment: I get the same error when the image fails to load (it's not in the working directory). You should add a check that `im.empty()` is not true, and perhaps adjust "Debugging>Working Directory" property on your project in Visual Studio. Or copy the image to the right place. Or use an absolute path to the input image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimal code that reproduces the error you mention looks as follows:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cv::Mat im;

    cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
    cv::Ptr<cv::SimpleBlobDetector> detector = cv::SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);
    detector->detect(im, keypoints);
}
```

Console contains

> OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 2494

and I get a exception from `detector->detect` with with the message

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF9A88C7788 in so03.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0000005BA676E230.

*Sidenote: The source of the error would be much more obvious in the debugger, if you had the debug symbols (PDB) available for the library. Unfortunately the package with precompiled binaries distributed from the OpenCV site doesn't contain those, which is why I prefer to build my own.*

It goes away when we pass a non-empty `cv::Mat` to `detect`:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cv::Mat im(100, 100, CV_8UC3);

    cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
    cv::Ptr<cv::SimpleBlobDetector> detector = cv::SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);
    detector->detect(im, keypoints);
}
```

From this we can conclude, that in your example, `imread` fails to load the image. This is entirely possible, since you don't check for this situation.

Add something like this right after your call to `imread`:

```
if (im.empty()) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to load image.\n";
    return -1;
}
```

Now, as to why the image is not loading correctly. One option, since you're using Visual Studio, is that you don't have your working directory set up correctly -- by default this is where the project file is located, which is probably not where the exe is. Either set `Debugging > Working Directory` appropriately in your project's properties, or use an absolute path to load the image.

Comment: No problem. If you feel this answers your question appropriately, feel free to mark it as accepted and perhaps upvote it. (It's those two arrows and what I guess is a tick mark on the top left of the answer).